# What is the closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If the set $A$ has been as follows, find the closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
$$A=\left\lbrace \frac{m+n}{2m+n+1}: m,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$$

Comment: Does your $\Bbb N$ include $0$?

Comment: no,$\mathbb{N}$ includes natural number. $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}$

Comment: For many of us $0$ *is* a natural number.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ is the collection positive natural numbers.

Comment: Where is this exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to figure out what fractions can be written in the form $\frac{m+n}{2m+n+1}$ for positive integers $m$ and $n$. Let $a=m+n$ and $b=2m+n+1$, where $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Then $b-a=m+1$, so

$$n-1=(m+n)-(m+1)=a-(b-a)=2a-b\;.$$

Thus, $2a-b\ge 0$, i.e., $b\le 2a$, and we have $a+2\le b\le 2a$.

Conversely, suppose that $a,b\in\Bbb Z^+$ are such that $2\le a<a+2\le b\le 2a$. Let $n=2a-b+1\ge 1$ and $$m=a-n=a-(2a-b+1)=b-a-1\ge 1\;;$$

then $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$, $a=m+n$, and $b=2m+n+1$. This shows that

$$A=\left\{\frac{a}b:a,b\in\Bbb Z^+\text{ and }2\le a<a+2\le b\le 2a\right\}\;.$$

- What is $\inf A$?
- What is $\sup A$?
- Show that $A=[\inf A,\sup A)\cap\Bbb Q$. Once you have that, getting $\operatorname{cl}A$ should be immediate.